# incorrect behaviour in nginx location preference

Tags: nginx

I have a nginx server set up to serve static files and an app server to serve the rest.

Required behaviour:

1. if the requests end with js|css|png|jpeg, serve locally
2. if the requests start with myapp/fonts, serve locally
3. else send to backend server

   ```
   location ~* ^/myapp-admin/(.*\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png))$ {
           expires 7d;
           autoindex on;
           alias {{ nginx_myapp_admin_staticfiles }};
   }

   location ~* ^/myapp-admin/fonts/ {
           expires 7d;
           autoindex on;
           alias {{ nginx_myapp_admin_staticfiles }};
   }

   location ~* ^/myapp/(.*\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png))$ {
           expires 7d;
           autoindex on;
           alias {{ nginx_myapp_staticfiles }};
   }

   location ~* ^/myapp/fonts/ {
           expires 7d;
           autoindex on;
           alias {{ nginx_myapp_staticfiles }};
   }


   location / {
       proxy_pass {{ myapp_app_backend_url }};
   }
   ```

However, currently, all the requests are being routed to the last block and end up reaching my app server.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex seems wrong

```
server {
  listen 8081;
  location ~(.*)(endwithjs|endwithcss)$ {
     return 301 https://www.perdu.com;
  }
  location ~^\/(startwithjs|startwithcss){
     return 301 https://www.google.fr;
  }

}
```

Nginx will handle request as the following :

http://localhost:8081/abc/abc/endwithjs => perdu.com

http://localhost:8081/startwithcss/Sdfsdf/sdf => google.fr